# Number of intersection points of plane and algebraic curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, intersection-theory, real-algebraic-geometry

Suppose $C\subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$ is an irreducible real-algebraic curve of degree $k$ and $P\subset \mathbb{R}^3$ is a plane. Suppose that $C$ intersects $P$ finitely many times. What is the best way to upper bound the number of points of intersection of $C$ with $P$? Is it $k+1$?

Here's one method to provide an upper bound. Find a projection that collapses $P$ to a line. Use Tarski-Seidenberg theorem to see that $C$ projects to a semi-algebraic set of degree at most $c_k$. Now use Bezout's theorem to determine that $\pi(P)$ has at most $c_k+1$ points of intersection with $\pi(C).$ Show that the projection $\pi$ maps together at most $d_k$ points from $C$ (this last step is a little sketchy), so that $C$ and $P$ have at most $c_k d_k$ points of intersection.

Is there a way to use Bezout's theorem more directly? Or a better method?

Comment: What you want is the generalized Bezout theorem: given two subvarieties $X,Y$ of $\Bbb P^n$ which intersect properly, $(\deg X)(\deg Y)=\sum_Z i(X,Y;Z)\deg Z$ where $Z$ ranges over the irreducible components of $X\cap Y$ and $i(X,Y;Z)$ is the intersection multiplicity of $X$ and $Y$ along $Z$. For the case of $X$ a curve and $Y$ a hyperplane, "intersect properly" means that no irreducible component of $X$ is contained in $Y$, and this would show $\#|X\cap Y|\leq k$. (I would be slightly worried whether you have the right definition of degree here - can you say explicitly what you mean?)

Comment: @KReiser Thankyou! Sorry, the $k+1$ was a mistake.